# How to detect the direction of a finger pointing

Tags: python, opencv, detection, direction

I am using python with OpenCV and pyautogui to play the game tetris (via a website) with your hands. In order to play the game there are 4 directions (up/down/left/right) that I want to detect to match with inputs for the pyautogui. I have tried so many ways to detect the direction of the finger that it pointing but nothing works consistently,any help on the current solution I am working on, or another idea would be great.

I am currently trying to use findContours with convexHull to detect the perimeter of the hand and attempt to find the sides with the smallest angle which in turn should tell me the side the finger is pointing. But I don't know how to extract that information.

I have tried using a BoundingRect to find which side is longer (w or h) then splitting the rectangle in half and seeing which side has more pixels in it (from the binary of the contour), but it wasn't consistent enough.

I have also tried using HoughLines and HoughLinesP to find a vanishing point, but I couldn't figure out how to get that to work.

Basically I am at a loss.

Edit: I'm trying to avoid MediaPipe so I can show I understand how to use the elements of openCV

Comment: Goggle mediapipe, it can do what you need.

Comment: @MarioAbbruscato Yes, I was hoping to do it without using a prebuilt library, but it may resort to that. I'll make an edit in the original question to note that I am aware of MediaPipe but would like to avoid it :) Thank you though!

Comment: You Need a point for every finger, and One point for the wrist. So a line from wrist point to a finger give you the orientation of the finger. Try to treshhold correctly the hand , then apply contours and convex hull to obtain the coordinate points of the fingers and wrist.

Comment: cv2.convexityDefects(contour, convexhull)  can be helpfull